# Android horizontal scrolling showing Cursor data

Tags: android, scroll, cursor, horizontal-scrolling

I have some text data in database which I have retrieved in a Cursor, and I am displaying it in a ListView. What I want to do now is that when you select click a particular row in the list its text content should be displayed in full screen and the user should be able to scroll horizontally (like scrolling between iPhone home screens) to view the contents of the Cursor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this can be achieved by overriding the onFling method